# Set width to match constraints in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I would like to constrain a View's left and right sides to it's parent view's margins and make it fill the allotted space. However, setting width to either `match_parent` or `wrap_content` appears to produce the same result.

Is there something equivalent to match_constraints (as opposed to match_parent and wrap_content)? Do `match_parent` and `wrap_content` affect the layout or are they ignored in the new constraint layout?

Comment: Why `match_parent` doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 160, accepted):

`match_parent` is not supported, so use `android:layout_width="0dp"`.  With `0dp`, you can think of your constraints as 'scalable' rather than 'filling whats left'.

Also, `0dp` can be defined by a position, where `match_parent` relies on it's parent for it's position (x,y and width, height)

Comment: why is this accepted answer?!? match_parent is not supported by constraint layout. And this answer give no way of implementing it.

Comment: match_parent is not supported.

Comment: This answer is correct. It clearly states match_parent is not supported. Also, to perform a reasonable alternative to a 'match_parent' setting, 0dp with constraints set to parent on left and right (margin 0 or pick to suit) will give the same result. The only thing that was really left out in this answer, which is in Arieck's answer, is the need to set constraints on both sides (or top and bottom for vertical). This is how I do it and i have not had any issues. Plus it works as a weight setting when used with other components.

Comment: If someone comes here seeking the answer for it not working. It seems that it got broken in beta. It seems to work in 1.0.2. Lesson learned - freeze the libraries, don't use opportunistic updates.

Comment: @Tequilaman comment can be the answer. He has rightly pointed out the way to implement it.
Create a constrain on either sides with 0dp margin, it does the trick.

Answer (score 195):

`match_parent` is not allowed. But you can actually set width and height to 0dp and set either top and bottom or left and right constraints to "parent".

So for example if you want to have the `match_parent` constraint on the width of the element, you can do it like this:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
```

Comment: Android team should make "match_parent" work. It would be extremely easy. Simply make match_parent provide the same functionality as if   the app was constrained to start and end of parent. Would be easy to detect vertically or horizontally.

Comment: But doesn't 0dp result in double-measure?

Answer (score 32):

Apparently `match_parent` is :

- **NOT OK** for views directly under `ConstraintLayout`
- **OK** for views nested inside of views that are directly under `ConstraintLayout`

So if you need your views to function as `match_parent`, then:

1. **Direct children** of `ConstraintLayout` should use `0dp`
2. **Nested elements** *(eg, grandchild to ConstraintLayout)* can use `match_parent`

Example:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/phoneNumberInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/phoneNumber"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: what about a ConstraintLayout nested in a ConstraintLayout, in your example change TextInputLayout to a ConstraintLayout?

Comment: @superuser
Then it's a constraint layout, same rules apply. 0dp

Answer (score 19):

`match_parent` is not supported by `ConstraintLayout`. Set width to `0dp` to let it match constraints.

Comment: and wrap_content is supported?

Comment: Yes, as far as I can tell.

Comment: wrap_content is supported

Answer (score 18):

From the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html#RelativePositioning):

> Important: MATCH_PARENT is not recommended for widgets contained in a
>   ConstraintLayout. Similar behavior can be defined by using
>   MATCH_CONSTRAINT with the corresponding left/right or top/bottom
>   constraints being set to "parent".

So if you want achieve `MATCH_PARENT` effect, you can do this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Note that the doc as of 2021 is even stronger. It's no longer worded as a "recommendation":
https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout


Note: You cannot use match_parent for any view in a ConstraintLayout. Instead use "match constraints" (0dp).

Answer (score 8):

You can check your Adapter.

```
 1 - MyLayoutBinding binding = MyLayoutBinding.inflate(layoutInflater);
 2 - MyLayoutBinding binding = MyLayoutBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, viewGroup, false);
```

I had a same problem like you when I used 1.
You can try 2.

Comment: This is gold! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

For making your view as match_parent is not possible directly, but we can do it in a little different way, but don't forget to use Left and Right attribute with Start and End, coz if you use RTL support, it will be needed.

```
    <Button
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

in the office doc:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout

When a dimension is set to MATCH_CONSTRAINT, the default behavior is to have the resulting size take all the available space.

Using 0dp, which is the equivalent of "MATCH_CONSTRAINT"

Important: MATCH_PARENT is not recommended for widgets contained in a ConstraintLayout. Similar behavior can be defined by using MATCH_CONSTRAINT with the corresponding left/right or top/bottom constraints being set to "parent"

Answer (score 2):

set  width or height(what ever u need to match parent ) to 0dp  and  set margins of left , right, top, bottom to act as match parent

Answer (score -1):

If you want TextView in the center of parent..
Your main layout is Constraint Layout

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/logout"
     app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
     android:gravity="center">
</androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView>
```