# How to make View fill remaining space in ConstraintsLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

How to make `View` FrameLayout fill all remaining space in `ConstraintLayout`

I have xml like:

```
<ImageView
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_header"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="spread"/>
<FrameLayout
    android:background="#00FF00"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_default="spread"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header"
    app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/footer"
    android:id="@+id/task_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:background="#FFFF00"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_default="spread"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="spread"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
    <ImageButton
        style="?borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:id="@+id/btn_ar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_ar"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

There are header, footer and `FrameLayout` in the middle I want to make `FrameLayout` to fill all remaining space.

I don't understand, which properties I have to use to expand `FrameLayout`. Please help me!

EDIT: Or any solution with different layout.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This work, go with `ConstraintLayout` because has better performance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_header"
        android:minHeight="30dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="spread"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/task_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#00FF00"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_ar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap">

    </FrameLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_ar"
        style="?borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_ar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 64):

This is really simple. To make any view fill up the available space either horizontally or vertically, just set the `layout_width`/`layout_height` to `0dp` according to your need.

Comment: to clarify a bit, after setting 0dp, set the top to top of parent or bottom of view on top and set bottom to bottom of parent or top of view below.

Comment: Nice & sweet answer

Comment: Was always curious where the `0dp` is documented - and [here](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/responsive-adaptive-design-with-views#responsive_width_and_height) is one relevant place.  Aka 'match constaint'.

Answer (score 7):

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/task_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#00FF00"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_ar"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_default="spread"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap">

</FrameLayout>
```

This should work.

Explanation:

All you want is to make the top of this FrameLayout constraint to the bottom of the header, and the bottom of this FrameLayout constraint to the top of the footer.

After setting all the constraints, you still need to set the layout param of FrameLayout to match the constraint. In order to do this, you can try to set `layout_height` to `0dp`. This will make the height of FrameLayout have the effect of `match_constraint`.

For more detail, you can check this doc: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout (just search the keyword `match constraint` and you will find that block), or simply check this similar answer: [Set width to match constraints in ConstraintLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37603751/set-width-to-match-constraints-in-constraintlayout)