# How to set a view's height match parent in ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am creating a `layout`.I want to set my custom `toolbar`(Which is another layout) to the top of `layout` and the `FrameLayout` just below the `toolbar`. But the `FrameLayout` should get rest of the `layout`'s height (match_parent). How to achieve this using constraint layout ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set width to match constraints in ConstraintLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37603751/set-width-to-match-constraints-in-constraintlayout)

Comment: Please see my solution and check if it is exactly how you need.

Answer (score 12):

**Solution:** I'm assuming that you have your toolbar as another xml file, something like this:

**toolbar.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="60dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

then using `ConstraintLayout` use it with `FrameLayout` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Hope this helps. Please comment if you have any issues with it.

Answer (score 11):

Use `0dp` that is match_contraint in ConstraintLayout.

Like `android:layout_height="0dp"`

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Pankaj. I already did it, but did not help.

Comment: Not only `android:layout_height="0dp"` but adding `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` this line solved my problem.

Comment: @YogeshKatkar Yes that will required as you are using ConstraintLayout you need to set constraints. I thought you would be doing all these things, only height is not working.

Comment: I used left,right and top only bottom constraint was missing.

Answer (score 1):

give the toolbar an id , 
and in your frame layout set the width and height to `0dp` add the constraints like in this code..

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".Main2Activity">

    <Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="#ab1010"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </Toolbar>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:background="#f1f1df"
        >

    </FrameLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note, that unlike other viewgroups in android, constraintlayout should have **circular dependencies** between the child views. Herewith, you should use 0dp instead of 'match_parent' width and constraints for each side of the child view.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```