# Why does "Infer Constraints" in the UI Design Builder set the layout height and width of some views to 0dp?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, layout, view

- I clicked "Infer Constraints"
- My Text views were fine but my Button and EditText views' layout height and width are automatically set to 0dp, rendering them invisible.
- I'm not sure if it's a bug or just a natural effect of this feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`0dp` is not a bug, it means `match_constraints`; so android studio tries to infer the constraints according to how you laid out your views with relation to each other and to the parent `ConstraintLayout`.

For more info check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37603751/set-width-to-match-constraints-in-constraintlayout)